# How can I use mnemonics on JavaFX 8 Alerts

Tags: javafx-8, alert, mnemonics

I would like to be able to add accelerator keys for the buttons that are provided as a part of the Alert Dialog Controls included with JavaFX.

I am unsure if this is possible using the standard alert types ERROR, INFORMATION, CONFIRMATION, WARNING?

I created my own login window - which doesn't use an Alert structure and it works as follows:

[image]

When the stage opens up.

Then when the user hits the "ALT" key:

[image]

I would like the ability to "Hot Key" the buttons on the Alerts in the system.  However, I am unsure if I can use the standard alerts, or if I need to create my own, and if so, how should I do that.

I really would like to use the Dialogs natively, if at all possible.

Thanks.

Comment: When setting mnemonics inside FXML they are done with an underscore, like "_Menu", have checked that?

Comment: These are Alerts so I am not creating them in FXML.  Alert a = new Alert(AlertType.Confirmation); a.show().

Comment: As far as I understood your requirements, you need something like [Custom Login Dialog](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/), which works with pure JavaFX 8

Comment: I have my dialog working, I was asking about alerts in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood your question, I think it isn't possible without some extra code.

Looking [at the code of OpenJFX](https://github.com/Debian/openjfx/blob/master/modules/controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/control/Alert.java#L295) the labels of the buttons [are localized](https://github.com/Debian/openjfx/tree/master/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/resources) and fixed.

You might just want to create some buttons on your own [by using the apropiate constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Alert.html#Alert-javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType-java.lang.String-javafx.scene.control.ButtonType...-) which takes some buttons where you can override the existing ones.

EDIT: after rethinking everything, I tried to recreate your problem. [You can see that project on GitHub.](https://github.com/FibreFoX/stackoverflow-32610932).

This is the special code:

```
public void showCustomizedAlertWindow() {
    Alert a = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION, "some content text", ButtonType.OK, ButtonType.CANCEL, ButtonType.FINISH);
    ((Button) a.getDialogPane().lookupButton(ButtonType.FINISH)).setText("_finished");
    a.show();
}
```

But be aware, you are removing localization-support of that buttons.